# Can I use a unique index on an array of sub-documents in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, duplicates, mongoose

I want to prevent duplicate inserts of `RecordList`s, where two `RecordsList`s are the same if they have the same set of `Record`s, i.e. the same array of sub-documents. This is the schema:

```
var RecordList = new Schema({
  event: {type: ObjectId, ref: Event},
  creator: {type: ObjectId, ref: User},
  records: {
    type: [Record],
    unique: true }
  }, {strict: true, safe: true})
```

But it seems that the `unique: true` in `records` doesn't work; when I save a `RecordList` with the same exact array of `RecordSchema`s as an existing one in the database, the duplicate is successfully saved, though I'd like it to return an error.

I'm new to Mongoose, and looking at other SO questions and the Mongoose documentation for a long time didn't turn up anything as far as I could tell. Sorry if this has an obvious answer!

Comment: No, you can't. You'd need to come up with a hash or something of the values and store that as a field of the list.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, ok, thought so. I've actually already written the hash stuff, it was only afterwards that I thought there might be something built in to Mongoose. Thanks!

Comment: The only way it would be efficient is if the core DB could do it ... which it really can't. If you stored the records as a string you could of course do it, but then, you'd loose some query capabilities.